# Embedding web fonts in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, fonts, embedded-fonts

Is it possible to embed web fonts in a standalone HTML page using a dataURL or something similar, without having to load them from an external file or address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's when you [encode the font in base64](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-do-i-embed-google-web-fonts-into-an-svg). you will technically have a "gibberish string" representing that font. this will increase load times since base64 is very long.

there are tools online that do that for you. essentially, it takes the font file, encodes it in base64 and replaces the font location with the base64 encoded version.